# IIS 7 Can't read data from ASP.Net application services tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, configuration-files

I'm working on deploying a web application written in C# with ASP.Net Application services databases.

The application runs fine on the development machine.

Windows Server 2003 has been built to test the application.

The database has been scripted across using MS SQL Server GUI.

ASP.Net application services tables were created using an utility.

The connection strings are stored in the web.config and connectionStrings.config.

The application connects to the database successfully, but then it times out after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection string was hardcoded somewhere in the app...ahhh

Answer (score 1):

I think we'll need more than this to figure out why the timeout is happening. How do you know that the application is successfully connecting to the database?

If that's all the information I had and I observed those symptoms, I'd likely try to run SQL Server Profiler against the SQL instance in question to see what activity against the database is timing out.